# Setting the length of a float or number

Tags: python-3.x

I've been looking around to try and set the length of floats or decimals to 2 places, I'm doing this for a set of course work, I have tried `getcontext` but it does nothing.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
price = ("22.5")
#I would like this to be 22.50, but as it comes form a list and I use float a bit, so I have to convert it to decimal (?)
price = Decimal(price)
print (price)
```

But the output is:

```
22.5
```

If anyone knows a better way to set the length of a decimal to 2 decimal places (using it in money) or where I'm going wrong, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"float" is short for "floating point".  Read about floating point on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic and then *never* *ever* **ever** use it to represent money.

You're on the right track with `Decimal`.  You just need to watch out for the distinction between the precision of the *representation* and the *display*.

The `prec` attribute of the context controls the precision of the representation of values that result from different operations.  It does *not* control the precision of explicitly constructed values.  And it does not control the precision of the display.

Consider:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> Decimal("1") / Decimal("3")
Decimal('0.33')
>>>
```

vs

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> Decimal("1") / Decimal("2")
Decimal('0.5')
>>>
```

vs

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> Decimal("0.12345")
Decimal('0.12345')
>>>
```

To specify the precision for display purposes of a Decimal, you just have to take more control over the display code.  Don't rely on `str(Decimal(...))`.

One option is to normalize the decimal for display:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> Decimal("0.12345").normalize()
Decimal('0.12')
```

This respects the `prec` setting from the context.

Another option is to quantize it to a specific precision:

```
>>> Decimal("0.12345").quantize(Decimal("1.00"))
Decimal('0.12')
```

This is independent of the `prec` setting from the context.

Decimals can also be rounded:

```
>>> round(Decimal("123.4567"), 2)
123.46
```

Though be very careful with this as the result of rounding is a *float*.

You can also format a Decimal directly into a string:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(Decimal("1.234"))
'1.23'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print "{:.2f}".format(price)
```

This way there will be no need for globally set the precision.